# Nested JSON using ms sql server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, nested

I have a table with **USER_DATA** (user data table) with 2 rows (2 entries basically)

I created one nested JSON query ->

```
SELECT CONCAT( first_name,' ', last_name) AS displayName, 
       first_name AS givenName, last_name AS surname,
       identities = (SELECT login_name AS issuerAssignedId 
                       FROM user_data 
                        FOR JSON AUTO) 
 FROM user_data
  FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('users');
```

Here, I am getting this output ->

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "David Dave",
      "givenName": "David",
      "surname": "Dave",
      "identities": [
        {
          "issuerAssignedId": "System"
        },
        {
          "issuerAssignedId": "Administrators"
        }       
      ]
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Tony Padila",
      "givenName": "Tony",
      "surname": "Padila",
      "identities": [
        {
          "issuerAssignedId": "System"
        },
        {
          "issuerAssignedId": "Administrators"
        }
      ]
    }
```

But the problem is -> inside identities,

"issuerAssignedId": "System" ----> Belongs to Dave

"issuerAssignedId": "Administrators" ----> Belongs to Tony

But I am not able to stop the inner select query (Not able to map correctly)

The correct output should be --->

```
{
      "users": [
        {
          "displayName": "David Dave",
          "givenName": "David",
          "surname": "Dave",
          "identities": [
            {
              "issuerAssignedId": "System"
            }      
          ]
        },
        {
          "displayName": "Tony Padila",
          "givenName": "Tony",
          "surname": "Padila",
          "identities": [
            {
              "issuerAssignedId": "Administrators"
            }
          ]
        }
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Is there any relation ship between table `USER_DATE ` and `USER_DATA `? You are getting all the records from second table `select LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId **from** USER_DATE for JSON AUTO` try to add a condition to get only the records that you need

Comment: Is there any relation ship between table USER_DATE  and USER_DATA  -> it is one table.

Comment: I have a column in user data  as Login_Name -> which I want to rename as "issuerAssignedId", create a nested JSON for it and then whatever value that column has, will be saved in "identifiers"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the condition in the inner query and why do you want the identities to be a separate array in the JSON output.

I have updated the query as per my understanding please refer below sql, I'm not sure why you are having the `**` in the query

```
     SELECT CONCAT (
        FIRST_NAME
        ,' '
        ,LAST_NAME
        ) AS displayName
    ,FIRST_NAME AS givenName
    ,LAST_NAME AS surname
    ,identities = (
        SELECT innr.LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId
        FROM USER_DATA
        innr
        WHERE
        innr.LOGIN_NAME = ottr.LOGIN_NAME
        FOR JSON AUTO
        )
   FROM USER_DATA ottr
   FOR JSON PATH
      ,ROOT('users');
```

Comment: ** is nothing but (BOLD) in stackoverflow, if you want to BOLD specific work, put ** in front and back or just select the word and press ctrl + b

Comment: let me the query try once

Comment: I have used INNER and OUTER previously which are the key words, updated the alias names now. Please try now once

Comment: like -> Incorrect Syntax near WHERE (first "where" you added) followed by incorrect syntax near INNER (first "inner" which you added), same errors for others additions  too

Comment: IT WORKED, I AM ADDING IT AS ANSWER, Thank you, you are a genius and a life saver!

Comment: Thank you, Glad your issue is fixed.